# How to dynamically add OData Web Api routes *after* Application_Start?

Tags: dynamic, asp.net-web-api, routes, odata

I have an application where I need to add OData routes dynamically. I can add *regular* routes after Application_Start just fine, but am having trouble doing it with *OData* routes.

Here's how I'm trying to dynamically add OData Web Api routes. In my WebApiConfig, I add a Products route:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "ProductsRoute", routePrefix: "odata", model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }
}
```

Then in my ProductsController, I add the following call in the Products GET method, which is successfully called when I go to http:///odata/Products (yeah, a little weird, but it's one way to demonstrate adding a route after Application_Start):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.AddOrderRoute);
```

The WebApiConfig.AddOrderRoute method gets called correctly and executes without error:

```
public static void AddOrderRoute(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "OrdersRoute", routePrefix: "odata", model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    config.EnsureInitialized();
}
```

So you'd think that now I have an Orders route correctly configured. But when I go to http:///odata/Orders, I get the following error:

```
ExceptionMessage=The object has not yet been initialized. 
Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the 
application's startup code after all other initialization code.

StackTrace=   at System.Web.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.get_AttributeMappings()
   at System.Web.OData.Routing.Conventions.AttributeRoutingConvention.SelectController(ODataPath odataPath, HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.SelectControllerName(ODataPath path, HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataPathRouteConstraint.Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, String parameterName, IDictionary`2 values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraint(HttpRequestMessage request, Object constraint, String parameterName, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.ProcessConstraints(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpRouteValueDictionary values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
   at System.Web.Http.Routing.HttpRoute.GetRouteData(String virtualPathRoot, HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.Routing.HttpWebRoute.GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
```

Note that I'm calling `config.EnsureInitialized()` in AddOrderRoute.

What am I missing?

**NOTE:** If I call AddOrderRoute at the end of WebApiConfig.Register() method, my Orders route is available and working, so I know that my Order entity, context and controller are working fine. It's only when I call it once application initialization is done that I get the problem.

Comment: May I know why would you want to add a route dynamically? Given that one route can serve many entity sets.

Comment: We don't know the entities beforehand. The users specify new entities, then we allow them to do CRUD operations on their new entities at run-time. So our desired approach is to create a new odata route for their specified entity at run-time (after app start). Interesting question though - if we could add new entities to the same route after app start. Not sure how we would access multiple entities off the same route...

Comment: That would introduce create a CLR type at run time, for example, you originally have Product type, and users create Order, then you need to have a Order type. It is very hard to implement. In my point of view it is reasonable for a user to create an instance instead of a type. For multiple entities of the same route I'll put it in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I spent some time with the good folks over at MSDN and got an answer!

Here's the way the Orders entity route needs to be registered:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");

var route = config.Routes.Where(r => r is System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataRoute).First();
var odataRoute = route as System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataRoute;

config.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "OrdersRoute", 
    routePrefix: "odata", 
    model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
    pathHandler: odataRoute.PathRouteConstraint.PathHandler,
    routingConventions: odataRoute.PathRouteConstraint.RoutingConventions);
```

Nice. Now .../odata/Orders can be accessed no problem.

Comment: So this means that you have to add an OData route during app start, then re-use its PathHandler and RoutingConventions?

Comment: Have you figured out how to dynamically _remove_ OData route after it was added?

Comment: Wow what a nightmare. The OData Namespaces are terrible.

Answer (score 0):

As we talked in the comment, multiple entities of the same route:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
    builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
    config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "OData", routePrefix: "odata", model: builder.GetEdmModel());
}
```

Then you can issue both requests:

```
1. http:///odata/Products and 
2. http:///odata/Orders
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that the types are *unknown* at app start. I've already solved the creation of new CLR types at runtime using the CodeDom. My only remaining problem is making them available as odata entity sets.