# Add OData Web Api routes *after* Application_Start?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing, odata

I need to register OData web service after application start.
In case of dynamically configure EntitySets, etc.

If I register it in regular way

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

It's work ok, but I don't have all information about my EdmModel at startup, so I want to register it later. (by administrator selecting OData model for example)

But, if I register it after

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

It didn't work.

I tried to use solution from  [How to dynamically add OData Web Api routes *after* Application_Start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25293477/how-to-dynamically-add-odata-web-api-routes-after-application-start)
but it also didn't work.

I tried something like

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register2);
    }
```

and

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );

        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "ProductsRoute", routePrefix: "odata", model: builder.GetEdmModel());
    }

    public static void Register2(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders"); 

        var route = config.Routes.Where(r => r is System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataRoute).First();
        var odataRoute = route as System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataRoute;

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "OrdersRoute", routePrefix: "odata", model: builder.GetEdmModel(), pathHandler: odataRoute.PathRouteConstraint.PathHandler, routingConventions: odataRoute.PathRouteConstraint.RoutingConventions);
        //config.EnsureInitialized(); - commented or not commented same result
    }
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to dynamically _remove_ OData route after it was added?

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution, at first register empty model:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "ODataRoute", routePrefix: "odata", model: edmModel, pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(), routingConventions: new[] { new CustomControllerRoutingConvention() });
    }
```

and then I could register another model anytime with

```
        var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
        var odataRoute = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.OfType<ODataRoute>().First();
        var constr = odataRoute.Constraints;
        var pathRouteConstraint = new ODataPathRouteConstraint(odataRoute.PathRouteConstraint.PathHandler, edmModel, "ODataRoute", odataRoute.PathRouteConstraint.RoutingConventions);
        constr["ODataConstraint"] = pathRouteConstraint;
```

Without calling config.MapODataServiceRoute(...)